# How to run a single specific analyzer or filter in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to see how different analyzers and filters respond to my input. I don't want to run all analyzers defined for a field in my index mapping, I want to be able to run them 1) individually and 2) without reindexing.

It looks like it should be done this way:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard' -d 'this is a test'
```

as described at [Elasticsearch Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html), but it doesn't work for me. Has the API changed in some way?

This is what I am getting:

```
No handler found for uri [/_analyze?analyzer=standard] and method [GET]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, it works in Elasticsearch v 0.19 only.